# Use one script to post for multiple modals

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals that retrieve a list of names with a checkbox next to them. Each is viewing a different column in the database to see if that box should be checked or unchecked. I have a script to post any changes made (either checking or unchecking a box).

The question is, how do I use this script to post based on which modal is being used. As its written, it will only post (or change the value) in one column of the database, which is specified by an url to a php file.

```
$('.checked').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var Offurl= "set-off.php";
    var item_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var dataStringL="item_id="+item_id+"&off=";

    if($.trim(item_id).length>0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Offurl,
            data: dataStringL,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ },
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="success") {
                    alert('The on-tap list has been updated! To view the changes you can refresh the page!');
                } else if(data="failed") {
                    alert('something went wrong! Please try again');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
 });

$('.unchecked').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var Offurl= "set-on.php";
    var item_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var dataStringL="item_id="+item_id+"&on=";

    if($.trim(item_id).length>0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Offurl,
            data: dataStringL,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ },
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="success") {
                    alert('The on-tap list has been updated! To view the changes you can refresh the page!');

                } else if(data="failed") {
                    alert('something went wrong! Please try again');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
 });
```

Here is one of the modals. Not sure where to put the data-column part?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalUpdate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" method="post">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Update on tap</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-default">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Beer Name</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php echo  $Recent0; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="UPD" id="UPD" class="form-control" >
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `data` attribute to the modal

`data-column="column-a"`

and then inside your change listener, just as you use `$(this).val`, you should be able to do `$(this).data().column` and use that inside your $.ajax URL

Something like this if you want to use url params:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Offurl + "?column=" + $(this).data().column,
        ...
```

If you want to use a different url you can use a ternary as so:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).data().column === 'column-a'? offUrlA : offUrlB,
        ...
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47055/

Comment: Updated question to include one of the modals. Not sure where to put the data-column part?

Comment: it will go on the tag that `$(this)` returns, which in your model you do not have because you use `$(this).val` but none of your tags have values

Comment: I meant the first part data-column=“column-a” that goes in the modal.

Comment: Right, thats what I meant too.. You don't have enough information for me to write the rest of your code for you.

Comment: Sorry! I’m just learning this off someone else’s code. Flying blind as as you can tell.

Comment: throw a `debugger;` in  where you do your `$(this).val`  and open your console. When you hit the debugger run `$(this)` it will print out the tag that `$(this)` is referencing

Comment: Here is the entire page:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/udxsj94ne8w1e36/beers.php?dl=0

Comment: jquery.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://oddsideales.com/admin/manager/set-on.php".

Comment: That is what was in the console after checking the box. I put the debugger; right below the var val = $(this).val();
debugger;

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
<?php
   $Recent0 = "";
   $check ="";
   $sql220 = "SELECT * FROM beers ORDER BY id";
   $query220 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql220);
   $productCount220 = mysqli_num_rows($query220);
            if ($productCount220 > 0) {
                while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($query220, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $id0 = $row0["id"];
             $BeerName0 = $row0["BeerName"];
             $on_tap0 = $row0["on_tap"];

             if($on_tap0 =='1'){
             $check ='<input data-id="'.$id0.'" class="checked" type="checkbox" value="off" checked="checkd">';
             }else{
             $check ='<input data-id="'.$id0.'" class="unchecked" type="checkbox" value="on">';
             }

             $Recent0 .= '<tr class="gradeX">
                                            <td>'.$BeerName0.'</td>
                                            <td>'.$check.'</td>
                                        </tr>';
                }
            }
?>

<?php
   $Recent1 = "";
   $check ="";
   $sql220 = "SELECT * FROM beers ORDER BY id";
   $query220 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql220);
   $productCount220 = mysqli_num_rows($query220);
            if ($productCount220 > 0) {
                while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($query220, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $id0 = $row0["id"];
             $BeerName0 = $row0["BeerName"];
             $to_go0 = $row0["to_go"];

             if($to_go0 =='1'){
             $check ='<input data-id="'.$id0.'" class="checked_to" type="checkbox" value="off" checked="checkd">';
             }else{
             $check ='<input data-id="'.$id0.'" class="unchecked_to" type="checkbox" value="on">';
             }

             $Recent1 .= '<tr class="gradeX">
                                            <td>'.$BeerName0.'</td>
                                            <td>'.$check.'</td>
                                        </tr>';
                }
            }
?>
```

And then:

```
$('.checked').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val();
var Offurl= "set-off.php";  
var item_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var dataStringL="item_id="+item_id+"&off=";
if($.trim(item_id).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: Offurl,
data: dataStringL,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ 

},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
alert('The on-tap list has been updated! To view the changes you can refresh the page!');

}
else if(data="failed")
{
alert('something went wrong! Please try again');
}
}
});
}return false;
 });


 $('.unchecked').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val();

var Offurl= "set-on.php";   
var item_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var dataStringL="item_id="+item_id+"&on=";
if($.trim(item_id).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: Offurl,
data: dataStringL,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ 

},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
alert('The on-tap list has been updated! To view the changes you can refresh the page!');

}
else if(data="failed")
{
alert('something went wrong! Please try again');
}
}
});
}return false;
 });




$('.checked_to').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val();
var Offurl= "set-off-togo.php"; 
var item_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var dataStringL="item_id="+item_id+"&off=";
if($.trim(item_id).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: Offurl,
data: dataStringL,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ 

},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
alert('The To Go list has been updated! To view the changes you can refresh the page!');

}
else if(data="failed")
{
alert('something went wrong! Please try again');
}
}
});
}return false;
 });


 $('.unchecked_to').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val();

var Offurl= "set-on-togo.php";  
var item_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var dataStringL="item_id="+item_id+"&on=";
if($.trim(item_id).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: Offurl,
data: dataStringL,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ 

},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
alert('The To Go list has been updated! To view the changes you can refresh the page!');

}
else if(data="failed")
{
alert('something went wrong! Please try again');
}
}
});
}return false;
 });
```